# Instance of private class before auto

Tags: c++, subclass, auto

I'm trying to find how to instantiate an element of a private subclass "before auto", so how to make the second line of the main working fine:

```
class A{
private:
    class B{
    public:
        void f(){};
    };

public:
    static B getB(){ return {};};
};
int main(){
    auto x1 = A::getB();
    A::B x2 = A::getB(); // B is a private member of A , so i can't write A::B
}
```

Comment: So you want a C++03 solution?

Comment: You want a getter for a private subclass ? My brain has just dumped core..

Comment: `decltype` maybe?

Comment: @John3136 i would like to have a way to assign the return object of a getter of a private subclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be quite rare for this to be useful. I would recommend first figuring out *why* do this rather than *how* to do it.

There is no way to get `A::B` to work outside the scope of `A` given private `B`. But you can for example provide a public alias in a friend class, and use a similar declaration:

```
class A{
    // ...
    friend struct C;
};

struct C {
    typedef A::B B;
};

C::B x2 = A::getB();
```

Comment: yes it's rare, but for example in a iterator situation? yes the same thing you can achieve putting constructor inside the private interface and using a friend inside the container class related to, but it was just a my curiosity, so thanks

Comment: @Berto99 I cannot see how a private iterator would be useful. Can you describe?

Comment: in order to not build it if not with `begin()` or `end()`, and so instead of `B` you have `iterator` and instead of `A::getB()` you have `container<T>::begin()`